# What is the replacement for `watchOptions` in webpack-dev-server v4.15?

Tags: webpack, migration, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

I am migrating to **webpack-dev-server v4.15**, I got following error:

> Options has an unknown property 'watchOptions".

When I checked the official [migration doc](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md), it mentioned that, `watchOptions` has been moved to [`static`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverstatic) property.
Could anyone please help me to understand exactly which property `(directory, staticOptions, publicPath, serveIndex, watch)` from static object is representing `watchOptions` now.

Let say if currently I have:

> watchOptions: { ignored: ignoredFiles(/node_modules/)

So with which option I should use `ignoredFiles` now?

Any amount of help will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `static.watch` configuration is the replacement for `watchOptions`, see [v4.15.1/lib/Server.js#L914](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/v4.15.1/lib/Server.js#L914)

```js
devServer: {
    static: {
      watch: {
        ignored: /node_modules/,
      },
    },
},
```

`WDS` uses [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar#path-filtering) package to handle the file watch. You can find the `ignore` configuration of it. It accepts a regexp.

Comment: Thanks @Lin Du for the detailed explanation.